# DXA web-install.ps1 - access control list not in canonical form

Tags: dxa

I'm installing DXA 1.5, and running the `web-install.ps1` script. When it comes to set the folder permissions, I get an exception like this:

> C:\Users\dominicc\Downloads\SDL DXA .NET 1.5\web\web8\web-install.ps1 : Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "This acc
>   ess control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified."
>   At C:\Users\dominicc\Downloads\SDL DXA .NET 1.5\web\web8\invoke-web-install.ps1:1 char:1
>   + .\web-install.ps1 -distDestination "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DXAboxed" -sit ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [web-install.ps1], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,web-install.ps1

This causes the script to abort. What causes this and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

This problem seems to be an issue with Windows security rather than with DXA specifically. You can work around it by modifying the script as follows:

```
#Set folder permissions
Write-Host "Setting folder permissions on '$distDestination' ..."
$Acl = Get-Acl $distDestination
Set-Acl $distDestination $Acl
$Acl = Get-Acl $distDestination
$permission = "NetworkService" ,"FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission    
$Acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
Set-Acl $distDestination $Acl
```

The point is that if you use the `set-acl` cmdlet to write back the ACL exactly as it's just been read, it will fix the ordering of the ACEs. If you do this before calling `$Acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)` this call will succeed instead of throwing an exception.